# How to limit the content-editable <span> with number of LINES?

Tags: html, css, angular

I am Working in Angular 6.

Problem :

```
<span class="ed-cont" contenteditable=true #valueToDB>{{content}}</span>
```

How to limit the  with the number of Lines?

Found many Answer for limiting with characters. But I need to limit it with lines.

Comment: You could create a pipe that get in input the `{{content}}` and count every relative "<br>" that find. If the result is over N, then simpy return this string untill the N br.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `line-clamp`.

```css
.txt {
        overflow: hidden;
        width:200px;
        text-overflow: ellipsis;
        display: -webkit-box;
        -webkit-line-clamp: 4; /* edit this line */
        -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
        border:1px solid #ccc;
      }
```

```html
<div class="txt">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</div>
```

Comment: I should not enter any value beyond this line limit. Instead that limiting by characters, i need by lines.

Comment: @Sivabalakrishnan If so, you have to count characters.

Comment: This answer disregards the main point of the question - `contenteditable`... you are not showing here how to solve that, which will not work with `line-clamp`